# Unable to configure git terminal to push a already created project

Tags: git, github, terminal, repository

I have created a project and want to push it to git. I have created the repository on git and want to now push my code but I am not able to configure the git. I am getting the following error when I try to run **git push -u origin master**
Error:

```
fatal: 'git@github.com/dearestpankaj:cbb6c2bc8c0ea84120749a745fe59ab5de04d8b6/CoffeeDbApp' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have added my email and user name with following command:

```
git config --global user.email "my_email@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "my_git_user_name"
```

After this I did the following:

```
git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'my first commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com/my_git_user_name/MyRepositoryName
```

But with above command I get following error:
**fatal: remote origin already exists.**

```
git push -u -f origin master
```

with the above command, I get access right error.
I understand that I have to add my password somewhere but I am not able to find where to add it to my terminal.
I have now also created a personal token in the GitHub settings but still not sure how to use it.
Right now I only have master branch in my remote which is created by default. I want to push in this branch and then, later on, will add more branches for my work.

**Edit:**
I tried to add SSH key but when I still I am not able to push/pull. when I tried git push, I got the following:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

when I tried above command, I got the following error:
To github.com:dearestpankaj/CoffeeDbApp.git

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:dearestpankaj/CoffeeDbApp.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to adding SSH key as mentioned by Kevin, follow these steps:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git merge origin origin/master
... add and commit here...
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps to push a new codebase that exists on your computer to GitHub:

1. Create an SSH key: [instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)
2. Upload the SSH key you just created to GitHub: [instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
3. delete the old `origin` Git remote from your repository: `git remote remove origin`
4. if you haven't done yet, create a new repository on GitHub: [instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/github/getting-started-with-github/create-a-repo)
5. On the GitHub website for your repository, click on the `Code` button, select `Use SSH` if it's visible, and copy the URL. It should start with `git@github.com`
6. add the new `origin` Git remote: `git remote add origin [paste URL]` (replace `[paste URL]` with the URL you just copied
7. run `git push` to push to GitHub

Comment: Hi, I followed steps mentioned by you but still, it didn't work for me, please check my latest edit

Comment: You need to add the `--force` switch: `git push --set-upstream origin master --force`